# C# Function cannot return -- prevent compiler warning

Tags: c#, exception, attributes

I have a function that is guaranteed never to return. It logs data and throws an exception.

```
public int f()
{
    ... do stuff ...
    if(condition)
        BadUserData.Throw(... parameters...);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I get the error message "not all code paths return a value. I can fix this of course by a dummy return after the non returning function, but I wonder if there is an attribute or something I can apply to the Throw function it indicate that it never returns? I had a look and could not find one.

Comment: I think you'll have to have throw keyword in you if block.

Comment: If it either throws or returns 0, why not make the function void?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/21/never-say-never-part-one.aspx for some thoughts on this non-feature of C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't. Actually, to get the most appropriate call stack, I would have something more like below, where the method *creates* the exception but we `throw` it locally:

```
if(condition)
    throw BadUserData.CreateSomeFormOfException(... parameters...);
```

which solves both problems in one go.

Another lazier approach would be:

```
if(condition) {
    // throws <===== comments are important here ;p
    BadUserData.Throw(... parameters...);
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

Well instead of `BadUserData.Throw` actually `throw`:

```
public int f()
{
    ... do stuff ...
    if(condition)
        throw new Exception("... parameters...");
    else
        return 0;
}
```

or have this method return an Exception and then:

```
throw BadUserData(... parameters...);
```

Other than that, no, there aren't any attributes or anything that will make your code to compile.

Answer (score 3):

If the method's job is to log and then throw and exception, you sould change the method signature to be

```
public void f()
```

instead of

```
public int f()
```

This will take care of your compiler issue. It's also going to be a lot cleaner as you can omit the else section of the method body.

Answer (score 1):

Return the exception in `BadUserData.Throw` instead of throwing it and do:

```
public int f()
{
    ... do stuff ...
    if(condition)
        throw BadUserData.Throw(... parameters...);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have no other choice than adding a return statement with a dummy value, e.g. `return -1;`.